# Interface in C# what does it mean in this context

Tags: c#

Was going through this [code here](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/interoperability-between-microsoft-and-soa-12c/)

The code here confused me

```
private void sendMessage()
{
    IConnectionFactory wlsConnectionFactory;
    IQueue ordersQueue;

    IDictionary<string, Object> environment;
    IContext jndiContext;
```

In dot net and C# a I prefix means a Interface no ?
If the above statement is true what does this line mean for example

```
IQueue ordersQueue;
```

Would this program have worked if we had something like

```
Queue ordersQueue instead of IQueue ordersQueue ?
```

Comment: It means that the orderQueue variable can reference any concrete type that implements the IQueue interface.

Comment: It's a naming convention and generally safe to assume it's an interface, but it doesn't have to be. All it means is that the variable can be of any type that implements the interface `IQueue`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: So the program would work even if i had written Queue ordersQueue instead of IQueue ordersQueue ?

Comment: I... is just a standard way of naming interfaces, doesn't have to start with an I. Also only because it starts with an I doesn't mean it's an interface.

Comment: Only if `Queue` implements `IQueue`. But that limits you to only `Queue` when maybe a `SpecialQueue` would have worked. Definitely do some reading on interface programming in .NET

Comment: @DanielPersson and Yuck: Why don't you answer the question? Why do you comment it?

Comment: @user3249433 It would work but then you can't pass Queue around as an interface

Comment: @Yuck `Queue` doesn't need to implement `IQueue` if he writes it as `Queue someQueue = ...`

Comment: @PVitt I can't bring myself to whxre for rep with a question that's covered by MSDN.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil I'm making the assumption that the code relies on some features of an `IQueue`, so without rewriting it then yes `Queue` does have to implement `IQueue` as it's just a more general case of that "type".

Comment: later in the code you linked, you will find this: `ordersQueue = (IQueue) jndiContext.LookupDestination("jms/ordersQueue");` which is where the implementation of `IQueue` is loaded and assigned to our field.

Comment: What if i had Queue ordersQueue and later in the code do ordersQueue = Queue jndiContext.LookupDestination("jms/ordersQueue") ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, an `I` prefix *implies* an interface, but that's just a convention (albeit, a extreme widely-used convention)

```
  IQueue ordersQueue;
```

means that `ordersQueue` can be assign any type which implements the `IQueue` interface.